# In BCPL what does "of" do?

Tags: bcpl

I am trying to understand some ancient code from a DEC PDP10 written in BCPL. A sample of the code is as follows:

```
                test scanner()=S.DOTNAME then
            $(  word1:=checklook.up(scan.info,S.SFUNC,"unknown Special function [:s]")
                D7 of temp:=P1 of word1
                scanner()
            $) or D7 of temp:=SF.ACTION
```

What do the "D7 of temp" and "P1 of word1" constructs do in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unstoppable Martin Richards is *continuing* to add features to the BCPL language<sup>(a)</sup>, *despite* the fact that so few people are aware of it<sup>(b)</sup>. Only seven or so questions are tagged `bcpl` on Stack Overflow but don't get me wrong: I liked this language and I have fond memories of using it back in the '80s.

Some of the things added since the last time I used it are the sub-field operators `SLCT` and `OF`. As per the [manual on Martin's own site](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Emr10/bcplman.pdf):

> An expression of the form `K OF E` accesses a field of consecutive bits in memory. `K` must be a manifest constant equal to `SLCT length:shift:offset` and `E` must yield a pointer, `p` say.
>
> The field is contained entirely in the word at position `p + offset`. It has a bit length of `length` and is `shift` bits from the right hand end of the word. A length of zero is interpreted as the longest length possible consistent with `shift` and the word length of the implementation.

Hence it's a more fine-grained way of accessing parts of memory than just the `!` "dereference entire word" operator in that it allows you to get at specific *bits* within a word.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> *Including,* apparently, a version for the Raspberry PI, which may finally give me an excuse to break out all those spare PIs I have lying around, and educate the kids about the "good old days".

---

<sup>(b)</sup> It was used for at least one MC6809 embedded system I worked on, and formed a non-trivial part of AmigaDOS many moons ago.

Comment: I am using Essex University BCPL, and have since managed to get a manual which includes this word slicing feature which I now understand. I was particularly bemused as I am using it on a PDP10 which has a 36 bit word, so took me a while to comprehend the word and bit splits. Thanks for your response.